# MySQL Connection not available. Database PythonAnywhere for Telegram Bot, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere, py-telegram-bot-api

The problem is this: I run the script, everything works fine. a few minutes pass and the script shuts down, leaving this error.

here is the script:

```py
import telebot
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, BigInteger
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    telegram_id = Column(BigInteger, unique=True)
    money = Column(Integer)
    money_for_investing = Column(Integer)
    invited_friends = Column(Integer)

# Connect to the database
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlcon...', pool_recycle=3600)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Initialize the bot and set the access token
bot = telebot.TeleBot("BOT TOKEN")

# Define the /start command handler
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    # Get the user's input
    cash = 0
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    investing_cash = 0
    invited_friends = 0

    user = session.query(User).filter(User.telegram_id == user_id).first()

    # If the user is not in the database, store the data
    if not user:
        user = User(telegram_id=user_id, money=cash, money_for_investing=investing_cash, invited_friends=invited_friends)
        session.add(user)
        session.commit()

        # Send a confirmation message
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="You are registered.")
    else:
        # Send an error message
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="You are already registered.")

# Start the bot
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Error:

```py
20:15 ~/telegram $ python telegram_bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1719, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 1013, in _init_compiled
    self.cursor = self.create_cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 1361, in create_cursor
    return self.create_default_cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 1364, in create_default_cursor
    return self._dbapi_connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1083, in cursor
    return self.dbapi_connection.cursor(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 590, in cursor
    raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alexknowsbest/telegram/telegram_bot.py", line 51, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
  File "/home/alexknowsbest/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "/home/alexknowsbest/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/home/alexknowsbest/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/home/alexknowsbest/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 156, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/home/alexknowsbest/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 100, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alexknowsbest/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 6395, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "/home/alexknowsbest/telegram/telegram_bot.py", line 34, in start
    user = session.query(User).filter(User.telegram_id == user_id).first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2819, in first
    return self.limit(1)._iter().first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2903, in _iter
    result = self.session.execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1696, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1498, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1725, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2043, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1719, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 1013, in _init_compiled
    self.cursor = self.create_cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 1361, in create_cursor
    return self.create_default_cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 1364, in create_default_cursor
    return self._dbapi_connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1083, in cursor
    return self.dbapi_connection.cursor(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 590, in cursor
    raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) MySQL Connection not available.
[SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.telegram_id AS users_telegram_id, users.money AS users_money, users.money_for_investing AS users_money_for_investing, users.invited_friends AS users_invited_friends 
FROM users 
WHERE users.telegram_id = %(telegram_id_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: [{}]]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

I've been trying to fix this mistake for a day, I can't. I switch to different modules and still nothing happens. please help me solve this problem. I will be very grateful to you

Comment: Have you reviewed [Dealing with Disconnects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects)?

Comment: Hm... I have set `pool_pre_ping=True` and so far everything is fine, I will tell you if there is a problem.

Comment: requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=25)

Comment: According to their [docs](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingMySQL/), connections time out after 5 minutes, so `pool_recycle` should be set to a value of 300 or less

Comment: doesn't works...